# How to get Boostrap popover feature on an Html ActionLink in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-popover

I have a table with ActionLinks.  I am trying to figure out how to wrap these so that I can display a bootstrap popover feature. Any help is appreciated!

Here is what I have before trying to make any changes to allow for Bootstrap-Popover feature:

```
<div class ="container">
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th>Group Name</th>
        <th>Description</th>            
        <th>Last Change</th>
    </tr>

<% foreach (var item in Model) { %>

    <tr>
        <td>
        <% if (isAdmin) { %><%=Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.GroupId }, new { @class = "fa fa-pencil", title = "Edit Group" })%>
        </td>
        <td><%= Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.GroupId }, new { @class = "fa fa-info_circle", title = "Group Details"})%></td>
        <td><%= Html.Encode(item.GroupName) %></td>
        <td><%= Html.Encode(item.Description) %></td>            
        <td><%=Html.Action("ConvertToLocalTime", new {utcTime = item.LastChange})%></td>
    </tr>

<% } %>

</table>
</div>
```

Comment: Where is your script? - see [here](http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/twitter-bootstrap-tutorial/bootstrap-popovers.php)

Comment: var originalLeave = $.fn.popover.Constructor.leave;
$.fn.popover.Constructor.leave = function (obj) {
    var self = obj instanceof this.constructor ?
        obj : (obj.currentTarget)[this.type](this.getDelegateOptions()).data('bs.' + this.type)
    var container, timeout;

    originalLeave.call(this, obj);

Comment: if (obj.currentTarget) {
        container = $(obj.currentTarget).siblings('.popover')
        timeout = self.timeout;
        container.one('mouseenter', function () {
            clearTimeout(timeout);
            container.one('mouseleave', function () {
                $.fn.popover.Constructor.leave.call(self, self);
            })
        })
    }
}

$('body').popover({ selector: '[data-popover]', trigger: 'hover', placement: 'top' });

Comment: That is my script. Sorry about formatting. Not sure what stackoverflow changed it.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, you can add code to your question by clicking on the 'edit' link underneath it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know the question is quite old, but I ended up here. So, that's what I got. Maybe I can help someone.

The Tooltip and Popover data-apis are opt-in, meaning you must initialize them yourself.

`<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
    })
</script>`

and, then, in your code:

```
@Html.ActionLink(" ", "Delete", null, new { id = item.id}, new { @class = "glyphicon glyphicon-remove", data_toggle ="tooltip", data_placement = "top", title = "Delete" })
```

Comment: Thanks Lucas.  I have upvoted and marked your solution as the Answer.  Please upvote my question if you think it may be useful to others. Cheers!